# Converting java object to a array or list of its values

Tags: java, arrays, object

Suppose I have a POJO like this:

```
class User {
    String id;
    String name;
    String job;

    // constructors here
}
```

I create a new object of user like this,

```
User u = new User("1", "Ash", "dev");
```

I need to convert this object to an array or list containing `["1", "Ash", "dev"]`.
Also, I need to maintain the order of values according to fields.
I have implemented this using reflection. Is there any better approach?

Comment: If you want it to work with any class, reflection is the only way. You could also have your POJOs implement an interface with a ``toArray`` method or something of that sort.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I guess that is really any of my business but I had ask. Anyway, why reflection if you know the class? Add a method that returns an array instead to the User class.

Comment: Actually, for example, I used only three fields. In reality, my POJO have lots of fields and I want to avoid use getter for each field while printing the value. If I can get the values in order I can just pass that instead.

Comment: Even using reflection won't solve you problem for sure. From `Class.getDeclaredField` javadoc *The elements in the returned array are not sorted and are not in any particular order.* Now, I would guess this will depends on the byte-code so on the same version, it is most likely to be OK but in different version, this could change. But you can always sort the fields based on the name first.

Comment: What about using an auxiliar list and putting the fields inside in the constructor order?

Comment: @AxelH, I suspect the same. My implementation works as expected but am a little worried though.

Comment: @dcalap pls elaborate

Comment: Basically am looking for a flat map operation kind of thing

Answer (score 1):

Here would be a simple solution to output the value always in the same order using reflection.

This is not perfect but the idea here is to show how to order the array of fields using something that **should** remain the same. Here the name.

```
public static void toArray(Object o){
    List<String> list;

    list = Arrays
            .stream(o.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .sorted((f1, f2) -> f1.getName().compareTo(
                    f2.getName())).map(f -> {
                try {
                    return Optional.ofNullable(f.get(o));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return Optional.empty();
                }
            })
            .map(opt -> opt.orElse("null"))
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

And a quick example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    toArray(new TestClass("Foo", 1, 2L));
    toArray(new TestClass("Bar", 3, 4L));
    toArray(new TestClass(null, 5, 6L));
}
```

> [1, 2, Foo]
>   [3, 4, Bar]
>   [5, 6, null]

For a more complete solution, I would use an annotation to set the position of each values but also to be able to ignore some fields.

Comment: I use a similar approach but I got your point on using the annotations

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in many ways!

Maybe overriding the `toString` Method is the thing you want!

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "[" + id + "," + name + "," + job + "]";
}
```

Then you can use `split()` method of `String` class to access the fields.

You can also have another method which returns an array of string containing the fields you want.

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem I could have generated the list or array itself. I want to avoid using getter or field variables in this case.